# How to return actual data from a serializer Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to test a register_customer api endpoint I'm working on on Django, but I'm getting the the user_id as a response instead of the actual user's data.

```
{
    "data": {
        "user_id": 15
    },
    "message": "Thank you for registering"
}
```

I have a Customer model that has a OneToOne relationship with the CustomUser

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user_id = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And here's my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Customer, CustomUser
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    confirm_password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "phone_number",
            "password",
            "confirm_password",
        ]

    def validate_password(self, value):
        # Password must be at least 8 characters long
        if len(value) < 8:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Password must be at least 8 characters long."
            )

        # Check for at least one uppercase character
        if not any(char.isupper() for char in value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Password must contain at least one uppercase character."
            )

        # Check for at least one special character
        special_characters = "!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:'\",.<>/?"
        if not any(char in special_characters for char in value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Password must contain at least one special character."
            )

        # Check for at least one number
        if not any(char.isdigit() for char in value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Password must contain at least one number."
            )

        return value

    def validate_email(self, value):
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This email is already in use.")
        return value

    def validate(self, data):
        # Check if password and confirm_password match
        password = data.get("password")
        confirm_password = data.get("confirm_password")
        logger.debug({password, confirm_password})
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Passwords do not match.")

        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # Remove 'confirm_password' from the data before creating the user
        validated_data.pop("confirm_password", None)
        # Retrieve password directly from validated_data
        password = validated_data.get("password")
        # Ensure that password is not None before validating its length
        if password is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password cannot be empty.")
        self.validate_password(password)

        # Create the user without 'confirm_password'
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

        # Set the password for the user
        user.set_password(password)

        user.save()
        return user

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ["user_id"]
```

And here's the view I'm testing:

```
class RegisterCustomerView(APIView):
    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.debug(f"Request_data: {request.data}")
        user_data = request.data
        # Validate UserSerializer first
        user_serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
        
        if user_serializer.is_valid():
            # Access validated data after validation
            user_data = user_serializer.validated_data
            if user_data:
                try:
                    user = user_serializer.save()
                    customer_data = {"user_id": user.id}
                    customer_serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=customer_data)
                    if customer_serializer.is_valid():
                        customer_serializer.save()
                        # Automatically send verification email upon successful registration
                        send_verification_email(user)
                        return Response(
                            {
                                "data": customer_serializer.data,
                                "message": "Thank you for registering",
                            },
                            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        )
                    else:
                        raise ValidationError(detail=customer_serializer.errors)

                except IntegrityError as e:
                    logger.error(f"Integrity error: {e}")
                    return Response(
                        {"detail": "Integrity error. Please ensure the data is unique."},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                    )
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")
                    return Response(
                        {"detail": "An unexpected error occurred."},
                        status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                    )
        else:
            raise ValidationError(detail=user_serializer.errors)
```

I've tried this on the CustomerSerializer

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(source='user.email')
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name')
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(source='user.phone_number')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ["email", "first_name", "last_name", "phone_number"]
```

But I didn't get the actual response as expected rather

```
{
    "detail": {
        "email": [
            "This field is required."
        ],
        "first_name": [
            "This field is required."
        ],
        "last_name": [
            "This field is required."
        ],
        "phone_number": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any assistance. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get `CustomUser` data in `Customer` model, you can define nested serializer for `CustomUser` model and add it to `CustomerSerializer`:

```
class CustomUserNestedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone_number',)


class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_id = CustomUserNestedSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('pk', 'user_id',)
```

also in your view, you are creating `Customer` object by using the serializer. Instead of that, just create customer directly with model and then pass the object to serializer to return it:

```
customer_obj = Customer.objects.create(user_id=user)
customer_serialized = CustomerSerializer(customer_obj).data
return Response(customer_serialized, status=status.HTTP_20_CREATED)
```

---

Your modified serializer for `Customer` is ok just modify the `source` to `user_id` instead of `user` as your field name is `user_id` in `Customer` model and also and `read_only=True` to fields.

Comment: Great, it works, thanks for the response.